# How to perform an web oauth login in firebase testlab?

Tags: firebase, oauth, automated-tests, firebase-test-lab

I'm trying to test my app on firebase testlab. 
The app requires web based oauth login and the test is stuck in the first screen. 
What's the way to provide oauth login ability to an app?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Robo test, you can provide a user-name and login as part of the test run or provide a RoboScript.

If this is an instrumentation test, you have other mechanisms at your disposal for scripting the test.